# Why is there a delay when I deploy my app to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

When I deploy my app to Heroku, I see a delay in the changes being reflected. I have verified that this is not because of the browser cache. What's the cause for this delay - is there a A-B deployment strategy that Heroku employs by default?

Comment: Hm, how long is the delay?

Comment: are you using the no-downtime-push labs feature?

Comment: No, I'm not. strangely enough, this affected only one of my apps. The issue does not appear for my other apps. Thanks for the tip!